# Stripping multiline comments in C++ with RegEx

Tags: c++, regex, comments, c++11

Assume that I have a var `std::string sourceCode;` where I have loaded a cpp source file. Now I want to remove all comments with the included regex classes from tr1 (now they are fully included as I use the Microsoft compiler) - single-line is easy but multi-line not. It is not about just replacing a comment with a space etc. it's about to keep the correct number of lines. Assume we remove a comment which is 5 lines long, this space should then be filled with 5 newlines so that I am able to backtrack code and compute with the correct line numbers.

My code so far:

```
std::regex singleLinedCommentReg("//.*");
sourceCode = std::regex_replace(sourceCode, singleLinedCommentReg, std::string(""));
std::regex multiLinedCommentReg("(/\\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\\*+/)");
std::for_each(
    std::sregex_iterator(sourceCode.begin(), sourceCode.end(), multiLinedCommentReg),
    std::sregex_iterator(),
    [&](const std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>& match) -> bool {
        // TODO: Replace the current match with an appropriate number of newlines.
        return true;
    }
);
```

Can anyone give me some advice on that?

**EDIT #1**

I do **NOT** want to provoke comments about the discussion whether it makes sense to use RegEx for this kind of doing! Please just assume the input is clean and as expected.

Comment: It's not as easy as you think. Consider the source `string s = "not // a /* comment ...";`

Comment: That's a pretty bold assumption, considering the code you posted in your question would break your regex.

Comment: You will probably need to perform some phases of translation. Line continuations are performed before most anything else is even lexed: http://codepad.org/LbarZgMg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach using regex is way off and too complicated. You are trying to use a regular language (regex) to parse a situation that is at least as complex as a context-free grammar. If you split things up and do part of the processing in C++ you'll get it done but it'll look messy.

If your goal is to write a function that strips all of the comments out without losing the new line characters I suggest that you generate a parse using one of the many parsing  tools available.

This took less than 5 minutes to create and is functionally what you are looking for. You can modify this to your hearts content.  It will generate a lexer with flex 2.5.4 or flex 2.5.35

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
%}


cbeg    "/*"
cend    "*/"
cppc    "//"
nl  "\n"|"\r\n"

%option noyywrap
%x mlc 
%%
{nl}        { fputs(yytext, stdout); }
{cbeg}      { BEGIN(mlc); }
{cend}      { fprintf(stderr, "Error: found end of comment without a beginning\n"); return -1; }
{cppc}.*    /* eat up the comment */
.       { fputs(yytext, stdout); }

<mlc>{cend} { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
<mlc>{cbeg}     { fprintf(stderr, "Error: Found /* inside another /* comment"); return -1; }
<mlc>.      /* eat up everything else */

%%

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        yylex();
}
```

---

Addendum:

The above is a fully functional program.  You can generate the .c using:

```
flex -t foo.l > foo.c
```

and you can compile it using

```
cc -o foo foo.c
```

Now something like

```
./foo < source.c > source-sans-comments.c
```

will generate the new source file.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use two regexen. The first would remove all single-line comments (these would not affect the line numbers).

Then, use another regex for removing the multiline comments, and loop over each one until there are no more:

```
regex mlc("\\/\\*[^(\\/\\*)]*?\\*\\/");

string data = something;

match_results<std::string::const_iterator> searchresult;

while (regex_search(data, searchresult, mlc)) {
    const string& match = searchresult.str();

    auto newlinecount = std::count(match.begin(), match.end(), '\n');

    data.replace(searchresult.position(), match.length(), newlinecount, '\n');
}
```