# Stripping comments from c++ code while retaining line numbering

Tags: c++, gcc, comments

I'd like to strip the comments from a c++ file. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394040/543913) provides the following solution for this:

```
gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E test.c
```

However, this command appears to collapse long multiline comments. This causes behavior differences if the macro `__LINE__` is used.

Can the gcc solution be salvaged to not change `__LINE__`-dependent behavior? Or, a non-gcc solution would work fine too.

Example test.c:

```
int main() {
        /*
         *
         *
         *
         *
         * comment 1
         */
        // comment 2
        return 0;
}
```

Output using gcc 4.9.2:

```
$ gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E test.c
# 1 "test.c"
int main() {
# 10 "test.c"
 return 0;
}
```

If we delete `// comment 2`, then we instead get the desired output without comment collapsing:

```
$ gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E test.c
# 1 "test.c"
int main() {







 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good point. Probably not. Ask the GCC mailing list.

Comment: Well, having such like _"`__LINE__`-dependent behavior?"_ sounds not to  be a really clever idea. Can you elaborate that use case please?

Comment: Does it have to be a gcc solution? How about [a flex/c program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886410/stripping-multiline-comments-in-c-with-regex/8886750#8886750)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Unfortunately explaining the use case will take quite a bit of effort. I fear that may derail an otherwise well-defined question.

Comment: @Beta It does not need to gcc. I'm not familiar with flex but I can look into your linked answer if something better doesn't show up.

Comment: @jxh I updated question details with gcc version and example input/output.

Comment: [decomment.text](https://github.com/vitaly-t/decomment) can do that, using option `space`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GCC, the `#` directives with the numbers and file name correspond to line numbers, and thus maintain proper `__LINE__` values.

Comment: Aha! I actually simplified my problem statement somewhat - it was not gcc's compiled output that was having `__LINE__` problems, but rather a python process that was reading the comment-stripped `gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E` output and failing to match the original source line-by-line. Now that I know how to interpret the # directives, I can adjust my python script appropriately to match correctly. Thanks!